# PPTPD not working on virtual machine running Kali Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I need to capture non-http traffic from my iPhone. Using a proxy will only capture port :80 and :443 traffic which will not work for me as the traffic I am trying to capture is not from either of these ports. I believe that if I have a VPN I will be able to capture this traffic. Both my virtual machine and my iPhone are on the same network.

I am trying to run a PPTP VPN on a Kali Linux VirtualBox virtual machine using PPTPD. My network adapter settings are as such

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN3ru.png]

I have tried following several tutorials but every time I get an error on my iPhone saying the server is unreachable.

I am confused as to how to go about this. In my pptpd conf file what should be my localip and my remoteip be? What should my network settings be for my virtual machine? How do I set up PPTPD just for LAN?

Any help would be very appreciated. This is my first time asking a question on serverfault so sorry about any mistakes (i.e. formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not exactly what you wanted, maybe you can setup a wireless network with DHCP giving out the IP address of a machine with wireshark on it as default gateway. From that machine, you can forward everything to the internet and it should be transparent to the iphone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out. Is there any way to view https traffic. Charles proxy has a SSL Relay Proxy system which allows for viewing unencrypted packets. Is there any way to implement something similar with your method?

Comment: I haven't tried that. It will not be easy even if it's possible.